# ESP32 core update problems

Tags: macos, esp32, arduino-ide

I updated my Arduino IDE to the latest ESP32 core but when compiling get the following error:

```
[3057] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/nq/2hn7ngl12sl6qm83hf__7rvr0000gn/T/_MEISjMicX/libpython3.8.dylib': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/nq/2hn7ngl12sl6qm83hf__7rvr0000gn/T/_MEISjMicX/libpython3.8.dylib, 10): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /var/folders/nq/2hn7ngl12sl6qm83hf__7rvr0000gn/T/_MEISjMicX/libintl.8.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /var/folders/nq/2hn7ngl12sl6qm83hf__7rvr0000gn/T/_MEISjMicX/libintl.8.dylib
exit status 255
/private/var/folders/nq/2hn7ngl12sl6qm83hf__7rvr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/7BDD5E08-7004-4B2A-8A25-28F75E6FCEE0/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder returned 255
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module.
```

I tried to pip load the library terminal returned the following:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dy.lib (from versions: none)
```

System:

- Mac OS X 10.13
- Arduino 1.8

Comment: I don't have time to put together a proper complete answer, but you're trying to use Python binaries that are built for macOS 11 on macOS 10.13. 10.13 is very old. If you're using a computer capable of running macOS 11, the easiest fix is to update the OS. If you downloaded this version of Python then you'll need an older one built for your version of macOS. If you can't upgrade, you're not likely to be able to use the latest version of almost any software, as your OS is years out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a previous version of ESP32 library from the board manager, it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I have bought an ESP32 Kit of the brand freenove. This ESP32 board is the ESP-Wrover-E with the following features:

Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz

When I tried to verify the board, I ran the blink example but got the same error.

The current setup of my system at the moment of getting the error was:

**Computer:** iMac 21.5" Mid 2011, 20 GB RAM

**Operating System:** Mac OS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6

**IDE:** Arduino 1.8.9

After search a diagnostic and solution for the error I have decided to follow the recommendation of the previous comment in this entry: "***Try installing a previous version of ESP32 library from the board manager, it works for me!***", and It works for me. And the following are the steps I have followed with some technical comments in the process

**Diagnostic:**

The problem is that the current ESP32 board library installed in my Arduino IDE is version 2.0.6 which is not compatible with the Mac OS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6. This is very clear in the error message: "***... libintl.8.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 11.0) ...***"

**Solution:**

1. **Update the Arduino IDE:**

I have decided to upgrade the Arduino IDE from version 1.8.9 to the last version available version  2.0.4-nightly-20230216. This step does not solve the problem but, with this, you have a better and upgraded version of the boards and libraries software. The new version of Arduino IDE provides the ESP32 board library version 2.0.6 out of the box.

2. **Downgrade ESP32 Board Library:**

Finally, the error is solved by installing manually a previous version of the ESP32 Board Library, y my case I have installed **version 1.0.6**.

I have tried with all the ESP32 Board Library versions 2.0.5, 2.0.4, and 2.0.0, but none of the versions 2.X.X works properly. For me only version 1.0.6 works like a charm!!.

[Blink Example working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu2Q8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to 1.0.6 worked for me as well.
I'm on Mac OS 10.14.6 Mojave, and Arduino2 is 1.18.15

The failure started when I installed newer version of the ESP32 board manager library 2.0.11 ( 15 Sep 2023)
I did not remove the Board Manager Library 2.0.11, but instead selected 1.0.6 and clicked on Install. Compiled it, successfully.